# Redirect from iframe to the new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have been building widget that accept user input and then once everything checked it will redirect user to the original web site.

However the best I achieved for now is that redirect will be opened in parent window rather then in new window.

Right now I am using:

```
$(parent.location).attr('href', asoRequestURL);
```

However I would like to open redirected page in new window rather then in parent windows.

Is it possible ? If yes then can you give me example?

Comment: This is not a proper usage of jQuery. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some horrible problem with `window.open(asoRequestURL);`?  I know it's not technically jQuery, but so far as I can tell it would take a plugin to be able to do.  Is it really worth downloading a plugin to replicate such simple functionality?

EDIT: [Here is all the information you could ever want on `window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open); it may not be ultraclean jQuery smooth, but this isn't really what jQuery is meant for.

Here is a function to make it ultra-cool-smooth using objects for parameters and such:

```
function openWin(url, name, params) {
    if (params != undefined && typeof params == 'object') {
        var paramStr = '';
        for (var p in params) {
            paramStr += p + '=' + params[p] + ',';
        }
        paramStr = paramStr.substr(0, paramStr.length - 1);
        window.open(url,name,paramStr);
    }
    else {
        window.open(url,name);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
openWin('http://blah-blah/', 'myWin', {width: 400, height: 400, menubar: 'no'});
```

Answer (score 2):

To open a new window in Javascript:

```
window.open('http://example.com');
```

Pop-up blockers, however, may refuse to open the window, so be prepared.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the parent URL...

```
 parent.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

If you want to open in a new window...

```
 window.open('http://www.example.com/', 'nameWithoutSpaces', '{features}');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it in a hyperlink and controlling the behavior of the hyperlink (if it can be clicked or not) via javascript.

```
<a href='http:://example.com' target='_blank'>example</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I just need to generate URL from user input and Google map api and redirect the user to new window.